# How can I delete one cookie with capybara instead of all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I can do a `page.driver.browser.clear_cookies` to clear all cookies in my feature spec, but what if I want to clear a specific cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try `page.driver.browser.set_cookie("#{cookie_name}:")`, which should set it to an empty value.

Method: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/blob/e6e2351a15cabf620152eb938e5cacb514fe1529/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb#L177

Answer (score 1):

Old question I know, but you can use [`Selenium::WebDriver::Manager`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/manager.rb) to do more with cookies without having to add another gem (i.e., the thoughtbot capybara webkit-specific one referenced in the accepted answer) and that can be accessed through `page.driver.browser.manage`. For this question in particular you can use:

```rb
page.driver.browser.manage.delete_cookie(name)
```